# Applying Green's Theorem to a Closed Complex Contour Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

How would one apply Green's Theorem to the following complex contour integral: $\oint_\gamma $ $\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{-u}-1)}du$.

Where $\gamma$ is the Hankel Contour (counterclockwise) and R is the region inside.

Note: Essentially, we are coming in from $-\infty$and going around the unit circle and then back out again to $-\infty$.  The two paths coming in and out will cancel each other, as the only pole is at $u=0$.
Attempt:

Rewrite $f(u)$ in the form $a(x,y)+i(b,xy)$

Let $u=x+iy$ and $s=\rho+i\sigma$.

$$\frac{u^{s-1}}{e^{-u}-1}=\frac{(x+iy)^{(\rho-1)+i\sigma}}{e^{-x-iy}-1}=\frac{\exp\big[((\rho-1)+i\sigma)\log(x+iy)\big]}{e^{-x-iy}-1}$$

$$=\frac{\exp\big[((\rho-1)+i\sigma)\log\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan(y/x)}\right)\big]}{e^{-x}(\cos(-y)+i\sin(-y))-1} $$

$$=\frac{\exp\big[((\rho-1)+i\sigma)\left(\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+i\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)\big]}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)-ie^{-x}\sin y}$$

$$\frac{\exp\left[\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)+i\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)\right]}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)-ie^{-x}\sin y}$$

$$\scriptsize =\exp\left[\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right]\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)-ie^{-x}\sin y} $$

$$\tiny =\frac{\exp\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)^2+(e^{-x}\sin y)^2}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)\right]\left((e^{-x}\cos y-1)+ie^{-x}\sin y\right)$$

$$\tiny = \frac{\exp\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)^2+(e^{-x}\sin y)^2}\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)(e^{-x}\cos y-1)-\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)e^{-x}\sin y \\ +i\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)e^{-x}\sin y+\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)(e^{-x}\cos y-1)\right)\end{matrix}\right].$$

Therefore,

$$\small a=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)^2+(e^{-x}\sin y)^2}\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)(e^{-x}\cos y-1) \\ -\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)e^{-x}\sin y\end{matrix} \right]$$

and

$$\small b=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{\rho-1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)-\sigma\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)}{(e^{-x}\cos y-1)^2+(e^{-x}\sin y)^2}\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)e^{-x}\sin y \\ +\sin\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+(\rho-1)\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)(e^{-x}\cos y-1)\end{matrix}\right] $$

Apply Green's Theorem by rewriting contour integral:

$\int_c f(u)du=$ $\iint_R (-\frac {\partial b}{\partial x}-\frac {\partial a}{\partial y})dA+i\iint_R (\frac {\partial a}{\partial x}-\frac {\partial b}{\partial y})dA$

Evaluating with Mathematica (Where the radius of the circle $\epsilon<2 \pi in$$\forall n \in\mathbb z$:$\int _{-\epsilon }^{\epsilon }\int _{-\sqrt{\epsilon ^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{\epsilon
   ^2-x^2}}\frac{e^{-3 x} \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{\rho -1}{2}}
   \left(e^{-\text{$\sigma $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}
   \left(\frac{e^{-\sigma  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \left(e^x
   \left(e^{\text{$\sigma $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} (-\rho  y+y+x \sigma
   ) \left(-2 e^x \cos (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right)-2 e^{x+\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} y (\rho -1) \cos (y)\right) \cos \left((\rho
   -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+2 e^{2 x+\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} y (\rho -1) \cosh (x) \cos \left((\rho -1)
   \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-\left(e^{\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} y (\rho -1)+e^{\text{$\sigma
   $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} (-\rho  y+y+x \sigma )\right) \left(-2 e^x
   \cos (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right) \cos \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+\left(e^{\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}-e^{\text{$\sigma
   $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}\right) \left(-e^{3 x} (x (\rho -1)+y \sigma
   ) \sin \left((\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma 
   \log \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+e^x \left((-\rho  x+x-y \sigma ) \cos
   \left((\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right) \sin (2 y)-(2 (x (x+\rho -1)+y (y+\sigma ))+(x
   (\rho -1)+y \sigma ) \cos (2 y)) \sin \left((\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)+(x (x+\rho -1)+y (y+\sigma )) \sin
   \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+e^{2 x} \left((-x (x+\rho -1)-y (y+\sigma )) \sin
   \left(y-(\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+2 (x (\rho -1)+y \sigma ) \sin \left(y+(\rho -1)
   \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{\left(-2 e^x
   \cos (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right) \left(e^x \cos \left((\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-\cos \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right) \text{$\sigma
   $ArcTan}'\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x}\right)+i \left(-2 e^{-\text{$\sigma
   $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \left(e^x \cos (y)-1\right) \left(\cos
   \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-e^x \cos \left((\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)+\frac{2 e^{x-\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \left((x (x+\rho -1)+y (y+\sigma )) \cos
   \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-e^x (x (\rho -1)+y \sigma ) \cos \left((\rho -1)
   \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right) (\cos (y)-\cosh
   (x))}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{e^{-\text{$\sigma $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}
   \left(-2 e^x \cos (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right) \left(\left(x^2+y^2\right) \cos
   \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)+(y (\rho -1)-x \sigma ) \left(e^x \sin
   \left((\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-\sin \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)\right)}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{e^{-\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} (-\rho  y+y+x \sigma ) \left(-2 e^x \cos
   (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right) \left(e^x \sin \left((\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-\sin \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)}{x^2+y^2}+2 e^{x-\sigma  \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \sin (y) \left(\sin \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-e^x \sin \left((\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right)-\frac{e^{-\text{$\sigma
   $ArcTan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)} \left(-2 e^x \cos (y)+e^{2 x}+1\right)
   \left(e^x \cos \left((\rho -1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \sigma  \log \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)-\cos \left(y+(\rho -1) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \log
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)\right) \left((\rho -1) x^3+y \left(x^2+y^2\right)
   \text{$\sigma $ArcTan}'\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)}{x^2
   \left(x^2+y^2\right)}\right)\right)}{\left(-2 e^{-x} \cos (y)+e^{-2
   x}+1\right)^2}dydx$. However, I am not sure how to integrate this, or how changing $\epsilon$ would affect the integral. Essentially, does $\epsilon$ depend on anything (do you have to make it a certain number?) or do you just integrate with it?

Best Regards,
Thank You!

Comment: 0) Why Green's theorem??? 1) In general, the two path coming in and out won't cancel unless $z$ is an integer. 2) if $z$ is an integer, the integral can be evaluated by calculating the residue of the integrand at $u = 0$. 3) if $z$ is not an integer but $\Re z > 1$, you can shrink the "circle" part of the contour to infinitesimal small and the integral reduces to some standard integral over $[0,\infty)$ and the result is expressible in terms of Gamma and Zeta functions. 4) If $\Re z \le 1$ and $\ne 1, 0, -1,\ldots$, just analytic continue what you get in (3).

Comment: Okay, thank you. In this case would $z=s$? ...Is there a way to directly apply Green's Theorem, instead of using the Residue Theorem or The Cauchy Integral Formula. I am doing this because it will make a step in my process easier.@achillehui

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to directly apply Green's theorem. Green's theorem works on a more general class of function. The price to pay is it has much less property you can use to pin down the final value of the integral.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I will try the standard method.@achillehui

Comment: How would you express this integral in terms of the residues?@achillehui

Comment: When $z$ (or $s$) is an integer, you can replace the contour by the unit circle $S^1$ and

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{S^1} \frac{u^{z-1}}{e^{-u}-1} du
&= -\oint_{S^1} u^{z-2}\left(\frac{-u}{e^{-u}-1}\right) du
= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m-1}B_m}{m!}\oint_{S^1} u^{m+z-2} du\\
&= \begin{cases}
0,& z \ge 2\\
2\pi i \dfrac{(-1)^{m-1} B_m}{m!},& m = 1 - z \ge 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
where $B_m$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: Why is it that only when s is is an integer the paths cancel?@achillehui

Comment: And how did you find the pole at 0.3? @achillehui

Comment: When $s$ is not an integer, there is a branch cut start at $0$ and $u^{s-1}$ picks up a phase factor $e^{\pi i(s-1)}$ and $e^{-\pi i(s-1)}$ at upper and lower branch cuts. The contribution for the part of contour above and below the branch cut didn't cancel each other. There is no pole at 0.3. In the original comment. It is "..integrand at u = 0." and then "3) ...". These are two different sentences.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you for the help @achillehui